# Communication between Multiple Presenters in MVP

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, enterprise-architecture, mvp

I'm designing an application using the MVP pattern, but a few of the edge cases for the system rely on communication between multiple presenters.

> `View 1` calls `Presenter 1` which does `Operation A` returning `Result X`.
>
> `View 2`, `View 3`, and `View 4` are all interested in `Result X`. They each have their respective presenters, and can each respectively do `Operation A` and get `Result X`.

Our application has a `MainView` and a `MainPresenter` which effectively just house the other views and presenters.

One of the solutions was to give the `MainPresenter` references of `Presenter 1`, `Presenter 2`, `Presenter 3`, and `Presenter 4`. And having the result of `Operation A` call the other presenters.

Another was to implement a `Facade` layer that holds references to other presenters and it facilitates the other calls.

How have you handled this situation?

Comment: Fyi [Demystifying MVP and EventBus in GWT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kilmaSRq49g). It might be about GWT but I think it shows a good way to handle your problem using an event bus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my experience, if a result is needed in multiple places in the user interface, this suggests to me that the method for calculating it is a universal business rule, and therefore that rule has no business being implemented in a single presenter: it should be part of the domain model, instead.  At that point, no communication between presenters is needed, other than that they all reference the same domain model.

Comment: Interesting. My company is very headstrong on keeping models anemic, so all of our business logic is typically in presenters. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I've never understood the desire to separate domain logic and domain data. Martin Fowler has [a good article](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) on anemic domain models, which he considers an anti-pattern.